# Discord.js V12 how can I show all members with a certain role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

I am trying to make a command that will show me all the members with a certain role. The command should be like `$rolelist` and it shows all members' display names in a message that have the role `TEST ROLE`.
Help me out if you can :D

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "rolelist")) {
        const testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "TEST ROLE");
        const members = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.find(testRole)).map(member => member.user.username)
        message.channel.send(`These people currently have the TEST ROLE: \n${members}`)
    }})
```

Comment: The way I would do it is make a variable that's equal to an empty array. Next, using a forEach loop, for each member of a server, you want to .find() for a certain role and if it finds that role in the member's roles, you can .push() that user's ID into the array else the loop just goes on. This may not work though, just something I thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "rolelist")) {
        const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "TEST ROLE");
        const Members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == Role)).map(member => member.user.tag);
        message.channel.send(`Users with ${Role.name}: ${Members}`);
    };
});
```

You forgot to add `cache` to `message.guild.members` and `message.roles` since you are using V12.

Also, you were using the find function wrong.

You can't use it like this:

```js
member.roles.cache.find(testRole)
```

This is how you should use it:

```js
members.roles.cache.find(role => role == testRole)
```

Comment: Thanks, works. Also how could I make it so it displays the user's NICKNAMES?

Comment: You can use the `nickname` property of `GuildMember`. Example: `message.channel.send(member.nickname || member.user.tag)`. (nickname may be undefined. We're gonna use member's tag if it is.)