# How do I get my discord bot to list people in a certain role?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am trying to make my discord.js bot list the people in a certain role, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. What I want it to do is to list the people in a certain role, and refresh the embed every 2 minutes (or something like that). Right now, I'm getting an error saying `ReferenceError: message is not defined`.

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('732362918854787103')) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`List of Muted People`)
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setDescription(`List of people who are muted.`)
    const support = client.channels.cache.get('732360387101589596')
    if (support) support.send(embed);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js V12 how can I show all members with a certain role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646389/discord-js-v12-how-can-i-show-all-members-with-a-certain-role)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to make it refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should give you the result that you are looking for:

```js
// Get the role by its name
var yourRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "your role");
// Get all members that have the role
var members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == yourRole)).map(member => member.user.tag);
// Send message containing the members that were found (this can be implemented however you want)
message.channel.send(members);
```